# How to match optional and undetermined routes in AngularJS routing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

In AngularJS routing, I know a star (*) can match path with slashes, and question mark (?) can match optional path, but how to combine them? I want to match `/admin/tasks` and `/admin/tasks/arbitrary/path/with/slashes` together.

I tried this:

```
    $routeProvider.when('/admin/tasks/:path*?', {
        templateUrl: './templates/admin/task.html',
        controller: 'AdminTaskController'
    })
```

It can match `/admin/tasks/` and `/admin/tasks/arbitrary/path/with/slashes`, but not with `/admin/tasks`. It's strange because the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) says:

> Route path (matched against `$location.path`). If `$location.path` contains redundant trailing slash or is missing one, the route will still match and the `$location.path` will be updated to add or drop the trailing slash to exactly match the route definition.

Why can't the route match URL without the trailing slash?

Besides, in the doc,

> `path` can contain optional named groups with a question mark: e.g.`:name?`.

But actually using `?` alone cannot match path with slashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by duplication. it's not ideal, but it works:

```
.when('/system/:path?',{
    templateUrl:'assets/templates/pages/system.html',
    controller: "SystemController",
    controllerAs: "systemCtrl"
})
.when('/system/:path*',{
    templateUrl:'assets/templates/pages/system.html',
    controller: "SystemController",
    controllerAs: "systemCtrl"
});
```

now when people type in `http://localhost/system/files/15/delete` it recognizes it and if they just go to `http://localhost/system`